# VS 2013 Designer cannot get a namespace.class but I can create it at (Winforms) Load Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class (name it G) (derived from Control, so it's designable) which at one of its properties (call it M) instances a class (C) from another namespace (N) (which of course, is referenced in the project).
If I try to drag one of those "G" controls from the toolbox, the designer complains that it cannot find the required C in namespace N.

But I put code to instance one G in the Load event, and then assign a value to property M, which in turns instances C from namespace N, all works as expected and no exception or error are triggered.

Could someone explain where may I be wrong?

I'm using acronims because the full code is very large to reproduce here, even if once functioning, I'm planning to put it in the open source.

Regards

Comment: did you referenced the required dll in your custon control project? and imported the namespace?

Comment: Of course. I wrote "But I put code to instance one G in the Load event, and then assign a value to property M, which in turns instances C from namespace N, all works as expected and no exception or error are triggered. " Needless to say, all of that without resourcing to fully qualified names.